# left join on closest date

Tags: mysql, join

I have 2 tables

```
orders
+----+-------+--------+------------+
| id | email | status | date       |
+----+-------+--------+------------+
|  1 |       |      0 | 1427953986 |
|  2 |       |      0 | 1427954771 |
|  5 |       |      0 | 1427957427 |
+----+-------+--------+------------+

price
+----+----+-----+--------+----+-----+------+-------+------------+
| id | wd | bts | family | r  | tlv | kids | user  | date       |
+----+----+-----+--------+----+-----+------+-------+------------+
|  1 |  0 |   0 |      0 | 75 | 65  | 50   | int   | 1425894693 |
|  9 | 59 |   0 |      0 | 75 | 65  | 50   | mordi | 1435666477 |
| 10 | 59 |   0 |      0 | 75 | 65  | 50   | zack  | 1438790306 |
| 11 | 59 |   0 |      0 | 75 | 65  | 50   | zack  | 1438790326 |
| 12 | 59 |   0 |      0 | 75 | 65  | 50   | zack  | 1438790468 |
+----+----+-----+--------+----+-----+------+-------+------------+
```

How can I left join price to orders on the right date.
The result should join to orders table the row from price table
where the date of the order is grater or equal to date on price, but not greater then the next row (if exists)
for example

```
Example
+-----------+-------+--------+------------------+----------+----+-----+--------+----+-----+------+-------+--------------+
| orders.id | email | status | order.date       | price.id | wd | bts | family | r  | tlv | kids | user  | price.date       |
+-----------+-------+--------+------------------+----------+----+-----+--------+----+-----+------+-------+--------------+
|  1        |       |      0 | 1425894699       |  1       |  0 |   0 |      0 | 75 | 65  | 50   | int   | 1425894693   |
|  2        |       |      0 | 1438790336       |  11      |  0 |   0 |      0 | 75 | 65  | 50   | zack  | 1438790326   |
|  5        |       |      0 | 1438790478       |  12      |  0 |   0 |      0 | 75 | 65  | 50   | zack  | 1438790468   |
+-----------+-------+--------+------------------+----------+----+-----+--------+----+-----+------+-------+--------------+
```

Comment: How does the Order Table and Price table link ? via Id?

Comment: no, I based on date I want to the to price of the order to reflect the right price at that time

Comment: I don't understand the relation between your tables. if you are still in the dev phase, I would recommend that you create FromDate and ToDate columns for price and then on your left outer join you can use a between clause. 

if its too late to fiddle around with tables, view or temp table is your other option.

Comment: unfortunately this is an active system, there is no going back, I will rephrase my question

Comment: How do 2 rows in price table connect ?

Comment: Where did these 3 numbers **(`1425894699`, `1438790336`, `1438790478`)** under `order.date` appear from? They are not in either of the 2 tables.

Comment: And by the way, these are **not** dates.

Comment: I changed them to make it more clear, these are timestamps

Comment: I think you have some errors in your example. I think the column 'order.date' should be named 'orders.date'. The values of the column 'date' in the 'orders' table should be set to the values of the column 'order.date' of 'Example'. The columns email, status,wd,bts,... are all the same for all rows so they don't help to understand your question and you should remove them. It may be usefull to add an aditional text where both tables are presented side by side, the rows ordered by the date fields. I think this will make your intention more clear.

Answer (score 5):

There is a mismatch between the data and results in your question but I think you need a query like this. It's not going to be very efficient if the `orders` table is big:

```
SELECT 
    o.*,            -- pick the columns you want
    p.*             -- in the result 
FROM orders AS o
  LEFT JOIN price AS p
    ON p.date =
       ( SELECT pi.date
         FROM price AS pi
         WHERE pi.date <= o.date
         ORDER BY pi.date DESC
         LIMIT 1
       ) ;
```

Tested (with modified data in the `orders` table) in: [SQLfiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/accbc/1).

Comment: this did not work properly, I realize now there is no real way to achieve this
I will be forced to change my structure, thanks for trying

Comment: @phper, what does "not work properly" mean?

Comment: this LEFT JOIN is only 1 to 1 instead of 1 to many, isn't?

Comment: @neobie correct. The `LIMIT 1` ensures there is at most one row from `price` joined to a row in `orders` - well, assuming that there is a UNIQUE constraint on `price (date)`.